# Ghostscript not installing properly - find_library('gs') returns None

Tags: python, macos, installation, ghostscript, python-camelot

I'm attempting to install camelot, but for some reason Ghostscript won't install properly, so I keep getting the error `RuntimeError: Please make sure that Ghostscript is installed` whenever I try to use read_pdf.

When I went to check if Ghostscript was installed using `ctypes.util.find_library`, it cannot find it. I have installed Ghostscript using homebrew at the terminal (`Warning: ghostscript 9.54.0 is already installed and up-to-date.` when I tried to do it a second time, making me pretty certain that it's installed).

The camelot documentation tells me that something is wrong, but doesn't specify what.

Is anyone able to shed some light over where my errors are?

Answer (score 1):

You need install ghostscript for python and add bin folder to environment variable path.